# infinite order of element with element in an infinite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

If $G$ is a infinite group, then $G$ must have an element of infinite order.

Is this true?

I know that if $G$ is infinite cyclic, then it's isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

(I guess fact is irrelevant now)

Comment: You mean if $G$ is infinite *cyclic*, then it's isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$. In any case, what are you stuck on? What examples of infinite groups do you know?

Comment: @MikeMiller I know Z is infinite, R, C, Q

Comment: @MikeMiller what I'm stuck is would it be correct to say that 1 in Z is on infinite order since it generates all of Z?

Answer (score 4):

Consider $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^{\mathbb N}$ or $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Okay, so this statement would be false

Answer (score 2):

in an abelian group the elements of finite order form its *torsion* subgroup. a torsion group is infinite iff it is not finitely generated. $\Bbb Q / \Bbb Z$, cited by Hagen in his answer is a particularly clear example.